# what this error mean await message.guild.channels.create

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

```
let ticket = new Map()


module.exports = {
    commands: ['ticket'],
    description: "open a new ticket",
    callback: (message, async, text) => {
    const ticketChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name.toLowerCase() === `${message.author.username}--ticket`.toLowerCase())
        if(ticketChannel || ticket.get(message.author.id) === true) return message.channel.send("You already have a ticket currently open!")
        const ticketCreated = await message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    id: message.author.id
                },
                {
                    deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    id: message.guild.id

                }
            ]
        })
        ticket.set(message.author.id, true)

        let embed1 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTitle(`Your Ticket has been created!`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('RANDOM');

        let embed3 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor(message.member.displayName, message.member.user.displayAvatarURL())
        .setTitle(`Why have you created this ticket?`)
        .setDescription('Give a brief explanation on why you created this ticket.')
        .addField('Staff will be here shortly', 'Please wait without pinging anyone.')
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('RANDOM');

        ticketCreated.send(embed3)
        message.channel.send(embed1)
    } 
    }
```

i have this code and this is give me const ticketCreated = await message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-ticket`, {
error, what this is mean?

It's important to note that this is not my code, but I've made some changes to it for it to work, I'd love help

Comment: You don't seem to have quoted the actual error message

Comment: Check your node.js version, template strings were added in 4.0.0

Comment: Discordjs wont work on anything lower than v12 @Darth I dont think that's the issue